# How to simulate a click with jquery after preventDefault is called

Tags: jquery

When I click on anchor with target="_blank" and in jquery on click call preventDefault(), I want to do some stuff and then simulate the click event.

```
<a href="http://www.gogole.com" class="js-preview" target="_blank">Open link</a>
```

in jquery

```
$('.js-preview').on('click', function (e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff
    $(this).trigger('click');
 });
```

This doesn't work. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Whats the need of `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: I need to call ajax, do some stuff and then redirect to the link. I tried to call it in the ajax on success but I need to open the link in a new tab and I can't use window.open

Comment: You need to emulate what would have been the default behaviour. Maybe replace `$(this).trigger('click');` with `location.href = $(this).attr('href');`.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't open in a new tab. I don't know how to force it to open in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
```

Opens a new tab.

Comment: The browser requires to confirm that I want to redirect to a new page. The anchor target="_blank" doesn't require this. I need to emulate the target="_blank" functionality. Your answer is my current solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by calling click event on a hidden anchor avoiding preventDefault:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
   success:function(){
       .....
       $('.js-preview')[0].click();
   }
})
```